# FastEndpoints throws exception on app.UseFastEndpoints

Tags: c#, .net, fast-endpoints

I am going through [Get Started](https://fast-endpoints.com/docs/get-started) at FastEndpoints. I have followed the guide step by step for the bare minimum example, in a blank project, adding nothing else. But when I get to the line `app.UseFastEndpoints()` in the program.cs file, it throws the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in FastEndpoints.dll: 'The type initializer for 'FastEndpoints.Config' threw an exception.'

Adding some try catch, I can get the inner exception which is:

> Could not load type
> 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Metadata.IEndpointMetadataProvider' from
> assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions, Version=7.0.0.0,
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.

I have had no luck on neither Google nor ChatGPT (3.5). Has anyone seen this issue before and if so, how did you solve it?

## Code

(The code is exactly the same as in the Getting Started guide, but I'll add it for future reference)

### Program.cs

```
using FastEndpoints;

var bld = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();
bld.Services.AddFastEndpoints();

var app = bld.Build();
app.UseFastEndpoints();
app.Run();
```

### MyEndpoint.cs

```
using FastEndpoints;

public class MyEndpoint : Endpoint<MyRequest, MyResponse>
{
    public override void Configure()
    {
        Post("/api/user/create");
        AllowAnonymous();
    }

    public override async Task HandleAsync(MyRequest req, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        await SendAsync(new()
        {
            FullName = req.FirstName + " " + req.LastName,
            IsOver18 = req.Age > 18
        });
    }
}

public class MyRequest
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class MyResponse
{
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public bool IsOver18 { get; set; }
}
```

### MyWebApp.csproj

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="FastEndpoints" Version="5.18.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: It seems that rolling back to version 5.10.0 solves the issue, but that doesn't really explain what's happening. I haven't been able to confirm it as a known issue of FastEndpoints...

Comment: I just tested with exactly the same code, and for me, it works as expected.

Comment: @KristofferJälén that's odd. Are you also running version 5.18.0? And what version of the .NET SDK are you using? I'm at 7.0.1-preview. Perhaps that could be the issue.

Comment: I was using 5.18.0 and .NET 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a conflict with FastEndpoints version 5.18.0 and .NET SDK 7.0.100-preview (7.0.100-preview.6.22352.1 to be exact), which I was using.

At least updating to .NET SDK 7.0.401 solved the problem.

Alternatively it also worked by downgrading FastEndpoints to 5.10.0, but that's rarely a good solution.

Comment: good that you've sorted it out. was there a particular reason why you were using a preview version of the .net sdk? we don't usually develop against preview versions so haven't come across this issue before.

Comment: @DĵΝιΓΞΗΛψΚ only that I forgot that I was running a preview version on that particular machine :-)